# Symmetry of autocovariance matrix by multiplying feature matrix with its transpose

Tags: pca, transpose, symmetry

There is a mathematical theorem stating that a matrix A multiplied with its transpose yields a symmetric, positive definite matrix (thus leading to positive eigenvalues). 
Why does the symmetry test fails here for medium-size-random matrices?
It always works for small matrices (20,20 etc.)

```
import numpy as np
features = np.random.random((50,70))
autocovar = np.dot(np.transpose(features),features)
print((np.transpose(autocovar) == autocovar).all())
```

I always get 'FALSE' running this code. What do I do wrong?
I need the autocovariance matrix to perform a PCA but so far I get complex eigenvalues...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to errors in floating point arithmetic. Your matrix may be very close to a symmetric matrix numerically, but due to errors in finite precision arithmetic it is technically nonsymmetric. As a result a numerical solver may return complex eigenvalues.

One solution (sort of a hack) is to symmetrize the matrix, i.e., replace it with its [symmetric part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricPart.html). This matrix is guaranteed to be symmetric, even in floating point arithmetic, and it will be very close to the matrix you define (near machine precision). This can be achieved via

```
autocovar_sym = .5*(autocovar+autocovar.T)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is perfectly working. In the meantime I had the idea to use: 
`autocovar = np.round(np.dot(np.transpose(features),features),3)` 
which gives the same result.
Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I tried your code and it does pass your symmetry test. But it is **much** farther from the initial matrix, so I would be careful. To be more precise, if `X` is the original, nonsymmetric but numerically symmetric matrix, `X1` is defined as in my answer and `X2` as in your response, `np.linalg.norm(X-X1,'fro')` and `np.linalg.norm(X-X2,'fro')` are quite different. The former is accurate to about 12 digits, while the latter barely gets a single digit. Just a warning.

Comment: Thanks for letting me now that, I am quite new to Python and Machine Learning at all! :)